# PHP: substr_replace split characters with WP All Import

Tags: php, wordpress, import

I am using WP All Import to bring in a csv file. The file contains car registration plates in this format: YA08DXF

I'm looking to add a space 3 characters from the right i.e. YA08 DXF

Tried the following [substr_replace({fullregistration[1]}, " ", 3, 0)] which makes a space 3 characters from the left. Tried adding [substr_replace({fullregistration[1]}, " ", -3, 0)] but it breaks the import.

Not sure where I've got wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to split the series of characters 3 spaces from the end?

Comment: The {fullregistration[1]} is the WP All Import element from the csv file